# Issue in using Ternary operator in C++

Tags: c++

In hello.hpp

```
class hello  
{
public:
  enum type
  {
    trees = 0x03,
    plants = 0x04
  };
  void func( type a );
private:
  void func2(int b);
};
```

In hello.cpp

```
void hello::func( type a )
{
  func2((a = trees) ? 5 : 6);
}

int main()
{
  hello obj;
  obj.func(trees);
}
```

Whether I choose trees or plants ,I get the value 6. Why am I not getting 5? Have I dont anything wrong in the ternary operator?

Comment: Use comparison operator `==` like `(a == trees) ? 5 : 6`

Comment: Try (a == trees). Right now you are always comparing with trees since you are assigning trees to a.

Comment: Are you sure you rebuilt your program after changing from assignment to actual comparison?

Comment: It worked. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Following should work:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class hello {
public:
    enum type {
        trees = 0x03,
        plants = 0x04
    };

    void func(type a);

private:
    void func2(int b) {
        std::cout << b << std::endl;
    }
};

void hello::func( type a ) {
    func2((a == trees) ? 5 : 6);
}

int main() {
    hello obj;
    obj.func(hello::plants);
}
```

Pay attention to using comparison operator `==` instead of using assignment operator `=`.